# Get the selected value of a activex combobox using vba

Tags: vba, excel

How do i get the selected value of the combobox?

i have a combobox which has the values: "Corporate" and "Consumer".

I want to get the value that i selected, not the index, and store in a string.

something like this:

```
 string a = combobox.value;
```

(a -> Consumer)

thank you

Comment: @SiddharthRout, he said he was doing this from VBA in the description.

Comment: Yes he did :) but the code above code is C# ;)

Answer (score 9):

If your ComboBox is embedded in a spreadsheet you can use this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim cboCorpConsumer as ComboBox
Dim a as String

Set ws = Worksheets("YourWorksheetName")
Set cboCorpConsumer = ws.OLEObjects("cboNameFromActiveXProperties").Object

a = cboCorpConsumer.Value
```

Or in one line:

```
a = Worksheets("YourWorksheetName").OLEObjects("cboNameFromActiveXProperties").Object.Value
```

Comment: This is a correct answer; however, I was a little confused by the name of the combo box (is it cboName and you add a standard suffix onto it?). This answer assumes the name of the combobox is "cboNameFromActiveXProperties"  Likewise, if your combo box is named "ComboBox1" then you would use this syntax: `a = Worksheets("YourWorksheetName").OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.Value`

Answer (score 2):

`Value` has a capital "V" in VBA, but assuming `combobox` is the name of the ComboBox you created on the screen, the code you have will work (except that your assignment statement is wrong; see below).  If you don't know what the name of the ComboBox is, it is likely `ComboBox1`.  To check, look at the `Name` property in the VBA properties window.

Try this:

```
Dim a as String

a = combobox.Value
```

Comment: It didnt work. The combobox name is set to "CBSegmento" so i did exactly how you told.

    Dim Seg As String
    Seg = CBSegmento.Value

Error:

Run-time error'424':
  Object required

Comment: Where does your code reside?  Is the ComboBox on a user form or on the spreadsheet directly somewhere?