# how to read the value from a range of comboboxes?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, event-handling

I have an Excel sheet which contains 40 combobox. 
I have a worksheet_change event which has to be executed, only when these 40 comboboxes have a specified value.

I have this code (which I found here: [Get the selected value of a activex combobox using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082962/get-the-selected-value-of-a-activex-combobox-using-vba)) to read the value of a combobox.
I think I will be able to make a loop to read each combobox.

But my problem is setting the rule that uses the value for the event handler.
Can I create something (a variable) that is 1 or 0 whether or not the criteria is matched?

i have this code for reading the value of a combobox:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cboCorpConsumer As ComboBox
Dim a As String
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = Worksheets("simulator VER")
Set cboCorpConsumer = ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox2).Object
```

How could I achieve the above? Or should I use a rule for each combobox?

```
if combobox2.value = 1 then
if combobox3.value = 1 then
etc. etc.

if combobox40.value = 1 then execute event handler
```

**Edit 2:**
Thank you David Zemens. Your answer helped me to adjust it and make it work for my specific issue. this is the code I have now which works fine! (And I used this topic: [Call a function when only a specific Excel cell changes on Formula Recalculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631679/call-a-function-when-only-a-specific-excel-cell-changes-on-formula-recalculation) to make sure the code is only run when 2 specific cells are changed).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim objOLE As OLEObject
Dim cb As ComboBox
Dim a As String
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Target.Address = Sheets("simulator VER").Range("E6").Address Then

'## Make sure ALL comboboxes have the value of "1" before proceeding
For Each objOLE In Me.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(objOLE.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
        Set cb = objOLE.Object
        If cb.Value <> "No Promotion" Then GoTo Earlyexit
    End If
Next

'### The rest of your procedure code goes here:
With Worksheets("Simulator VER")
.Range("O21:O60").Copy
.Range("P21:P60").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

Else
    If Target.Address = Sheets("simulator VER").Range("E7").Address Then
        '## Make sure ALL comboboxes have the value of "1" before proceeding
        For Each objOLE In Me.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(objOLE.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
            Set cb = objOLE.Object
            If cb.Value <> "No Promotion" Then GoTo Earlyexit
        End If
        Next

        '### The rest of your procedure code goes here:
        With Worksheets("Simulator VER")
        .Range("O21:O60").Copy
        .Range("P21:P60").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
    Else
    End If
End If

Earlyexit:

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: **ALL** comboboxes must have the same value to allow this sub to execute?

Comment: true! Thank you for your answer. I am gonna try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **all** comboboxes must have the specified value to allow the `_Change` event to fire, you can do something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim objOLE as OLEObject
Dim cb As ComboBox
Dim a As String
Dim i As Integer

'## Make sure ALL comboboxes have the value of "1" before proceeding
For each objOLE in Me.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(objOLE.Object = "ComboBox") Then
        Set cb = objOLE.Object
        If cb.Value <> 1 Then GoTo EarlyExit
    End If
Next

'### The rest of your procedure code goes here:

EarlyExit:

End Sub
```

**Note:** technically the `_Change` event fires every time, but the `GoTo EarlyExit` aborts the procedure before the rest of your code is executed.

Comment: Yes, you need to use Application.EnableEvents=False in a sheet change macro. Remember to set it to true at the end,  too.  If this has helped solve your problem, do consider up voting ot making the answer as "accepted".  Cheers.