# Why does VBA generates a "Method or data member not found" error on a ComboBox, only when exiting Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, unspecified-behavior

I have two ComboBoxes, `Sheet1.Line_Items`, and `Sheet1.SerialNumber` and some code that interacts with the two.  Overall code works fine, but generates an "Method or data member not found" error when exiting Excel.

Is there a way to prevent that error from happening, or even a way to suppress the error so that users are not inconvenienced by the error when closing Excel?

My code:

```
Private Sub Line_Items_Change() ' Line_Items is an ActiveX ComboBox 

Dim ar As Variant

Dim i As Integer
Dim data As Dictionary

If Sheet1.Line_Items.Value Then
    ar = GetSerialNumber(Sheet1.Line_Items.Value)
Else
    ar = GetNoChoice
End If

With Sheet1.SerialNumber ` an ActiveX ComboBox - Generates ERROR on this line
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "0;60"
End With
```

[image]

When SerialNumber is working (while Excel is open)

[image]

The only thing I can figure is that `SerialNumber` gets destroyed somehow upon Excel closing?  ComboBoxes get destroyed and yet the `_Change` method gets called and can no longer find the combo box?

**How is Line_Items ActiveX ComboBox populated**

I have this code that clears the box, fills it with values, and then selects the first row

```
        Sheet1.Line_Items.Clear
          
        ' Update Line Items
        With Sheet1.Line_Items
            .ColumnCount = 2
            .ColumnWidths = "0;60"
        End With
                    
        ' Populate the Combo Box
        For i = 0 To UBound(ar, 2)
            With Sheet1.Line_Items
                .AddItem
                .List(i, 0) = ar(0, i)
                .List(i, 1) = ar(1, i)
            End With
        Next i
        
        ' Select first row
        Sheet1.Line_Items.Value = ar(0, 0)
```

**Other Considerations**

I have two comboboxes.  Updating one updates the other.  For example, I am currently thinking that when I close Excel, somehow `SerialNumber` combobox gets destroyed, and `Line_Items` value changes, and the `Line_Items_change` code gets called, and Excel tries to compile it, until it finds the code that refers to the `SerialNumber` box, which no longer exists. And throws an error

**New Error After using OLEObjects**

I changed my code from

```
Sheet1.SerialNumber
```

to

```
Dim SerialNumber As ComboBox
Set SerialNumber = Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(2).Object
```

The original error went away, but now I am getting this error:

Run-time error '1004': Method 'Worksheets' of objects '_Global' failed...

[image]

**New Error after fixing `_Global` error**

I changed the code from

```
Set SerialNumber = Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(2).Object
```

to

```
Set SerialNumber = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).OLEObjects(2).Object
```

The error message code remained the same, but the error message changed to:

```
Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class
```

[image]

**Next Error - Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class**

Top portion is during normal operation.
Bottom portion is after I close Excel file, it throws Debug error of "Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class", Run-time error '1004'

[image]

Error happens on this line:

```
    MsgBox TypeName(Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("SerialNumber").Object)
```

Comment: `Sheet1` does not have a `SerialNumber` member, and the code is failing to *compile*. Verify that `Sheet1` indeed has an ActiveX combobox named `SerialNumber`. Once the code compiles, the problem will be gone.

Comment: How is the `Line_Items` control populated?

Comment: ^ Rory, I've added code to my question

Answer (score 1):

`SerialNumber` does not exist, so the code doesn't compile.

Make sure there is a combobox ActiveX control named `SerialNumber` on `Sheet1`.

The compile error would manifest itself much earlier than "when exiting Excel", for example whenever any code in `Sheet1` gets invoked.

The macro is not working, if VBA cannot compile the code then no code in the module can run.

Maybe there's code that *removes* the `SerialNumber` combobox at run-time, or maybe the control was accidentally deleted or renamed. But no code in a given module can run if VBA can't compile it.

Comment: thanks ... I'll have to investigate this further somehow, because the `SerialNumber` control is working just fine while Excel is open.  I updated my question to showcase that it is working, and compiles.  So somehow somewhere combobox gets removed at runtime for some reason.  The sub that is triggered is `Line_Items_Change`, which is unexpected, because when I close the Excel, I am no longer making changes to the `Line_Items` combobox.  Thus, something must be triggering change in the combobox when I close Excel, which in turn invokes the code for a combo box that is no longer there.

Comment: to post update... I hope I was using it right, but RubberDuck did not find any meaningful references to SerialNumber.  It found the `_change` method, and it found the mention of SerialNumber in the code.  I am under impression that ActiveX control for `SerialNumber` is removed and then somehow the change control is triggered for `Line_Items`, causing my issue.... This does not seem to make sense though as both controls should be destructed at about the same time by Excel code, without calling any change control code

Comment: @Dennis avoid referring to ActiveX control by a programmatic identifier name if you're deleting these controls - deleting the control immediately breaks the code *as it's running*, which can't be a good thing. Try retrieving the controls by name at run-time instead (look into the `Worksheet.OLEObjects` collection)

Comment: Mathieu, you are talking about using something like `Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(2)` instead of `Sheet1.SerialNumber`, correct?

Comment: @Dennis yep. Basically if the controls are allowed to no longer exist, then their identifier name _should_ not be used in code.

Comment: Thanks.  There may be more going on.  I have updated my code, but I am now getting a new error about Method `Worksheets` - I have updated my question to show the error.  Is there a way to refer to worksheets in a different way..?

Comment: Thanks.  To follow up, I used `ThisWorkbook` and amended my question.  I am now getting "Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class" error.  This error runs deep.  Rubberduck highlights `Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` and says "The expression contains an indexed default member access to EXCEL.EXE;Excel.Sheets._Default".  Does that tell you anything..?

Comment: @Dennis that particular inspection is just a hint telling you about a hidden default member call; `.Worksheets(1)` is really `.Worksheets.[_Default](1)` which is equivalent to `.Worksheets.Item(1)`; 100% equivalent, and 0% related to the error; are your ActiveX controls named? Try retrieving them by name rather than by index.

Comment: are you talking about the name in the properties, correct?  I do have a name of `Line_Items ComboBox` under the properties of the ActiveX ComboBox.  When you say to retrieve them by name, do you mean using something like `Sheet1.Line_Items`?  If so, that is the code that started my original question that gave the "Method or data member not found" error

Comment: No I mean you pass a string literal containing the name instead of passing an integer: `.OLEObjects("Line_Items")`

Comment: Mathieu, I tried that approach, using `OLEObjects("SerialNumber")` because the error has moved to SerialNumber... I am strongly thinking it may be a good time to abandon the ActiveX approach and try recoding for Form Control.  I am not sure what else to try.  I posted a screenshot of the object when operational, and screenshot upon Excel Exit, when it throws the debug error...

Comment: @Dennis [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10655223/1188513)

Comment: When I use `Worksheets("Sheet1")` as in the linked answer it goes back to `Method Worksheets of object _Global failed` error.   When I add full qualifier of `Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` it goes to `Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class` error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231432/discussion-between-mathieu-guindon-and-dennis).