# How can I create a "two-column" drop-down box that is not an ActiveX Control, where I can programmatically populate this box and use it in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, combobox, form-control

**Background**

Suppose I have an example list with `(id, description)` pairs retrieved from a database and the list is like so:

```
1, aadvark
2, bubbles
3, carrot
4, depict
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to be able to:

1. programmatically copy the retrieved pairs from the database into the drop-down box to where the user can select one of the list choices
2. have user to be able to select desired `description` from above list
3. Use the `id` programmatically, for example, show the `id` in a `MsgBox` pop-up to confirm user's selection

**What I have done so far**

I was able to do this with an ActiveX ComboBox Control, where I set two columns, first column gets `id`, second column gets `description`.  User selects a description, and internally I use the resulting `id` for further processing.  But, I am having issues that I [cannot resolve with the ActiveX controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856571/why-does-vba-generates-a-method-or-data-member-not-found-error-on-a-combobox), and so I am seeking a different way, hoping there will be no issues with a different approach.

Can something similar be done with a Form Control combo box?  Or directly using Excel Cells?  Please advise.  Ideally I am seeking an answer that contains code where the desired functionality can be achieved with either a Form Control combo box, or with Excel's Cell construct and other native facilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Form Control combobox.

I don't have an English version of Excel at the moment to refer to and am guessing with regards to actual menu items, but right click a comboxbox that you embedded, and select Control Format(?), then on the far right tab (Control?), select the first text box (Input Range?) and select your range.

Assuming I have a comboxbox named cbTest on WorkSheet 1, in that sheet's module, I can refer to it like this.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oCBTest As Object

    Set oCBTest = Me.Shapes("cbTest")
    
    With oCBTest

        Debug.Print .Name
        
        Debug.Print .ControlFormat.ListCount
    
        Debug.Print .ControlFormat.List(1)

    End With

    Set oCBTest = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Replace `Debug.Print` with `MsgBox` if you're not sure how to use the Immediate Window.

This [link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/14/vba-for-excels-form-control-combo-boxes) shows various examples that might prove useful.